# Switch statement is not working as expected

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I have a little problem here the I need a little help with.

I think it's because of the switch statement, but I don't know exactly where.

But Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 underlines some things.

such as:

*`string input = Console.ReadLine();`* (that'd be at Line 24)

*`input.StartsWith("How"):`* (that'd be at Line 29)

It says:

> Type "bool" could not be implicitly converted to "string".

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Hello_World
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string random = string.Empty;
            string input = string.Empty;
            string choice = string.Empty;

            // Ask something
            do
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("World is a Savage Machine, whatever you ask, it'll give you a nasty answer.");
                Console.WriteLine("This is more a Joke, don't be sad if your Question isn't answered ;D");
                Console.Write("\nAsk World something: ");
                string input = Console.ReadLine();
            } while (input == "");

            switch (choice)
            {
                case input.StartsWith("Who"):
                    Console.WriteLine("Question: Who cares?");
                    break;

                case input.StartsWith("How"):
                    Console.WriteLine("Kys. That's how.");
                    break;

                case input.StartsWith("Where"):
                    Console.WriteLine("How does this make sense?");
                    break;

                case input.StartsWith("If"):
                    Console.WriteLine("If somebody would care, that'd be intresting.");
                    break;

                case input.StartsWith("When"):
                    Console.WriteLine("When the Dinasours were young");
                    break;

                case input.StartsWith("What"):
                    Console.WriteLine("What is the Purpose of this Question?");
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.Write("Not availible right now... we're working on it ;D");
                    break;

            }


            random = ("Das ist falsch.");

            // Antwort
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("The Answer to {0} is: {1}", input, random);
            Console.ReadKey();


            // Beenden
            do
            {
                     Console.Write("Press <Enter> to exit... ");
                     while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Enter) { }
            } while (true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `case input.StartsWith("Who")` returns a bool i guess, and your switch ask for a string

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense; you say you wish to switch on "choice", but choice is always empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never initialize `choice` and you are comparing `string` (`choice`) with `bool` (`.StartWith`)

Also you declared `input` twice.

You can split the input and take the first word into `choice` and switch on it like this:

```
string choice = string.Empty;

// Ask something
do
{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("World is a Savage Machine, whatever you ask, it'll give you a nasty answer.");
    Console.WriteLine("This is more a Joke, don't be sad if your Question isn't answered ;D");
    Console.Write("\nAsk World something: ");
    input = Console.ReadLine();
} while (input == "");

choice = input.Split(' ')[0];

switch (choice)
{
    case "Who":
        Console.WriteLine("Question: Who cares?");
        break;
    case "How":
        Console.WriteLine("Kys. That's how.");
        break;
```

Comment: the    _choice = input.split("")[0];_ seems like an error

Comment: fixed to -> choice = input.Split(' ')[0];

Answer (score 1):

Your issue with `string input = Console.ReadLine();` is because you've already initialised a variable with the name `input` on Line 14 with `string input = string.Empty;`.

To fix this, change `string input = Console.ReadLine();` to `input = Console.ReadLine();`

input.StartsWith also returns a boolean, which you're comparing to a string. Instead, use
`Case "Who":` etc.

Answer (score 0):

StartsWith return true/false and you are checking that value against a string.

Try this:

```
        switch (choice)
        {
            case "Who":
                Console.WriteLine("Question: Who cares?");
                break;

            case "How":
                Console.WriteLine("Kys. That's how.");
                break;
            ... OTHER CASES ...
            default:
                Console.Write("Not availible right now... we're working on it ;D");
                break;

        }
```

Comment: btw, you could prefer to check against lowercase or uppercase, to make it work the same if user introduces `Who`,`who`, `WHO`

Answer (score 0):

You code your `swtich` statement equivalent to a nested `if` statement. For your case, you'd need to switch for the first word of your string. Something like this:

```
// only if at least two words in string!
var firstWordOfChoice = choice.Substring(0, choice.IndexOf(" ") - 1); 

switch (firstWordOfChoice) 
{
    case "Who":
        Console.WriteLine("Question: Who cares?");
        break;
    // and so on...
}
```